# Calculate risk (under squared error loss) of MSE estimator of normal variance

Tags: statistics, estimation, decision-theory

I am given that $X_i\stackrel{\text{iid}}{\sim}N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. As part of a larger problem, I am to calculate the risk function of $\widehat{\sigma^2}_\text{MSE} = \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2$, using the loss function $L(\sigma^2,\widehat{\sigma^2}) = (\sigma^2-\widehat{\sigma^2})^2$.

I get stuck just trying to simplify down the horrible expression one gets when applying the definitions of risk and loss functions. Maybe I'm missing some shortcut or something. Any tips would be appreciated. So far I have:

\begin{align*}
R(\sigma^2,\widehat{\sigma^2}_\text{MSE}) = {} & \mathbb E[(\sigma^2 - \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2)^2]\\
= {} & \cdots\\
= {} & \sigma^4 - 2\sigma^2\frac1{n-1} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E(X_i^2-\bar X^2) \right) \\ & {} + \frac1{(n-1)^2}\mathbb E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^4 + 2\sum_{i<j} (X_i-\bar X)^2(X_j-\bar X)^2 \right]
\end{align*}

Any attempts to expand out that last big term seem to end in disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you know that $\displaystyle \frac 1 {\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2 \sim \chi^2_{n-1}.$

Recall that $\operatorname{E}(\chi^2_{n-1}) = n-1$ and $\operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1})=2(n-1).$

Then you have
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}\left( \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(X_i - \overline X \right)^2 \right) & = \sigma^2, \\[10pt]
\operatorname{var}\left( \frac 1 {n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( X_i-\overline X \right)^2 \right) & = \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}.
\end{align}

The bias is therefore $0$ and
$$
\text{mean squared error} = \left( \text{bias} \right)^2 + \text{variance} = 0 + \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}.
$$

Comment: That's exactly the sort of thing I thought/hoped I might be missing, thanks. I have to evaluate two other estimators, and for one of them I can clearly exploit this same relationship, since it's just a constant multiple of the original estimator in my post. But the other estimator is $\frac1{n+2}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$, and I'm having a hard time seeing how to use the insight in your answer to evaluate its risk, even though I suspect that's what I am supposed to do. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, both of the other estimators are confusing to me, now that I think about it. Since the other one is a biased estimator of $\sigma^2$ -- namely, $\frac{1}{n+1}\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2$ -- it's not clear to me how I can transform it to an expression in the variance of the first estimator ($\frac1{n-1}\sum(X_i-\bar X)^2$).

Comment: @Ceph : $$\begin{align}
& \operatorname{E}\left( \frac 1 {n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2 \right) = \operatorname{E}\left( \frac {\sigma^2} {n+1} \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2 \right) = \operatorname{E} \left( \frac{\sigma^2}{n+1} \chi^2_{n-1} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sigma^2 \frac{n-1}{n+1}. \qquad \text{Therefore, bias} = \sigma^2 \left( \frac{n-1}{n+1} - 1 \right) = \sigma^2 \left( \frac{-2}{n+1} \right). \qquad \text{And then }\ldots \end{align} $$

Comment: $$\begin{align}& \operatorname{var} \left( \frac 1 {n+1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2 \right) = \operatorname{var} \left( \frac {\sigma^2} {n+1} \cdot \frac 1 {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \overline X)^2 \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\sigma^4}{(n+1)^2} \operatorname{var}(\chi^2_{n-1}) = \frac{2\sigma^4(n-1)}{(n+1)^2}. \\[10pt]
\text{So } & \text{m.s.e.} = (\text{bias} )^2 + \text{variance} = \cdots
\end{align}$$

Comment: . . . . . and here I think it's worth doing the trivial algebraic simplifications: $$
\left( \frac{-2}{n+1} \right)^2 + \frac{2(n-1)}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{4 + 2(n-1)}{(n+1)^2} = \frac 2 {n+1}.
$$

Comment: Thus the mean square error of this biased estimator is smaller than the mean squared error of the best unbiased estimator. $\qquad$

Comment: thanks -- this really helps. We haven't been thinking of things this way in class -- We've only been talking about risk and loss, and it didn't occur to me to think of it as MSE and break it down to variance plus bias, but of course it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\widehat{\sigma}^2 \equiv \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X}_n)^2$. Since $X_i \sim \mbox{ iid } N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ we know that $Y \equiv (n-1)\widehat{\sigma}^2/\sigma^2$ is a $\chi^2$ random variable with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. Now, we can write:
$$\widehat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\left[(n-1)\widehat{\sigma}^2/\sigma^2 - (n-1)\sigma^2/\sigma^2 \right]= \frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\left[Y - (n-1)\right]$$
Using the preceding equality, we can write the MSE as follows:
$$MSE = \mathbb{E}[(\widehat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)^2] = \mathbb{E}\left[\left\{\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right)\left[Y - (n-1)\right]\right\}^2\right]= \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right)^2\mathbb{E}[\left\{Y - (n-1)\right\}^2]$$
Now, the mean of a $\chi^2(\nu)$ random variable is simply $\nu$ hence $\mathbb{E}[\left\{Y - (n-1)\right\}^2]= Var(\chi^2_{n-1})$. And the variance of a $\chi^2(\nu)$ random variable is simply $2\nu$. Substituting, we have
$$MSE = \mathbb{E}[(\widehat{\sigma}^2 - \sigma^2)^2] = \left(\frac{\sigma^2}{n-1}\right)^2 \times 2(n-1) = \frac{2\sigma^4}{n-1}$$